# Is there any mechanism in (the future version of) C++ which can make those things realistic?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have some template class called `friendly_point`, and a user-defined class called `foo`, and `foo` has some constructors with different arg number and types, eg, `foo()`,`foo(int)`,and `foo(int, char *)`.

I want to know if there is any method to implement `friendly_point` template so that I can write client code like this:

```
friendly_point<foo> obj1;
friendly_point<foo> obj2(1);
friendly_point<foo> obj3(1,"abc");
```

And even more, can `friendly_point` template be implementd in such a way that users of it can hook some memory pool to it, so all the objects it gives to the client comes form that pool?

Comment: What's so hard to use about smart pointers? Also, your first one won't matter if you write it like that because it's a function declaration.

Comment: I feel like you could delete everything in your question before the actual question without loss of necessary information...

Comment: `friendly_point<foo> obj1();` is a function declaration. ;-]

Comment: Also, no, that syntax is not possible. There's a proposal in the works right now about template argument deduction for constructors, which would remove the need for `make_xxx` functions.

Comment: The alleged verbosity of e.g. `std::make_tuple` is IMO mostly due to the naming scheme. I name my factories such that client code looks like `auto t = tuple(a, b, c, d);`. Similarly `std::bind` allows to very concisely express some functors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can already do this, just subclass a smart pointer and use [perfect forwarding](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_07.html) just like [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) already does. [Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4bqDKU$2):

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
struct friendly_ptr
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> p;
    template<typename... Params>
    friendly_ptr(Params&&... params) : p(new T(std::forward<Params>(params)...))
    {
    }

};

int main()
{
    friendly_ptr<int> p(1);
}
```

Comment: Interesting point, now what does that mean for [this](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3602.html)? Do you think there's a possibility of standard types allowing for this instead of using those verbose `make_xxx` functions?

Comment: Woo, that is just woderful! Though I can not fully understand, I will dig and study that.

Comment: @chris: I think the type deduction you're talking about is a completely different beast than the one necessary here, I don't know much about it.

Comment: @Mehrdad, `pair p(2, 4.5);` and `tuple t(4, 3, 2.5);` look pretty similar. Odd that desired syntax of that sort would not propose an existing feature. I do suppose the proposal is easier on the class writer, though.

Comment: @chris: No, they're completely different beasts. Those require the **class** template arguments to be inferred *from* the constructor call, whereas this one requires the **constructor** template arguments to be inferred from the constructor call... they look similar in usage because they're both calling the constructor but their nature is very different.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 introduces forwarding as illustrated by Mehrdad.

In C++03, you can try using templates ala:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper
{
  public:
    Wrapper() { }

    template <typename T1>
    Wrapper(const T1& t1) : t_(t1) { }

    template <typename T1. typename T2>
    Wrapper(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) : t_(t1, t2) { }

    template <typename T1. typename T2, typename T3>
    Wrapper(const T1& t1, const T2& t2, const T3& t3) : t_(t1, t2, t3) { }
    ...

  private:
    T t_;
};
```

Because the functions aren't checked for all errors until they're called, having placeholders for more arguments than `T` currently supports is ok.

You can use preprocessor macros to generate such forwarding functions for a generally ample but not insane number of arguments.  You may or may not find it easier to do so with the boost preprocessor library.

While this often suffices in simple cases, it's not a general solution.  Specifically - when you want to pass through a non-`const` parameter.  You could:

- leave `const` off in the argument list, but then non-`const` references can't bind to temporaries so the caller can't use a lot of normal expressions in preparing the parameter values, or
- accept `const` references then cast away `const`-ness, but that removes a deliberate protective feature of the language and may permit attempts to change genuinely `const` variables, including e.g. string literals - resulting in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this approach with me. This is actually more practical for my work since my team only use gcc 4.1.2, and my colleagues just don't care what is C++11.

Comment: This is not the same as the rvalue approach. The C++03 approach loses information.